# How can I quickly and dynamically load a CSV of relationship triples into Neo4j using apoc.periodic.iterate?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

**TL;DR: How can I *quickly* and *dynamically* load a CSV of relationship triples into Neo4j?**

---

**EDIT:** I'm now running the query below, but it is extremely slow; I project it to take <strike>six to seven</strike> many, many hours to complete. Please let me know if you know how to optimize this.

```
:auto LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///etymology.csv.gz' AS row
WITH row WHERE row.related_term_id IS NOT NULL AND row.related_lang IS NOT NULL
CALL {
    WITH row
    CALL apoc.merge.node([row.lang], {term_id: row.term_id}, {term: row.term, language: row.lang, term_id: row.term_id}) YIELD node AS node_a
    CALL apoc.merge.node([row.related_lang], {term_id: row.related_term_id}, {term: row.related_term, language: row.related_lang, term_id: row.related_term_id}) YIELD node AS node_b
    CALL apoc.create.relationship(node_a, row.reltype, {reltype: row.reltype}, node_b) YIELD rel RETURN rel
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS
RETURN count(*)
```

---

### Dataset

I would like to *quickly* and *dynamically* load a [dataset](https://github.com/droher/etymology-db) into Neo4j. The dataset has eleven columns, though I am only interested in the following columns:

`term_id`,  `lang`, `term`, `reltype`, `related_term_id`, `related_lang`, `related_term`

There are 3,884,337 rows in this dataset. Each row represents a relationship (`reltype`), so many nodes (comprised of `term_id`, `lang` `term` or the `related-` counterparts) are duplicated in the original dataset.

### Schema

Here is the Neo4j schema I envision:

Node:

- label: `lang`
- properties: `term_id`, `term`, `lang`

Relationship:

- label: `reltype`
- property: `reltype`

### [Success] Loading Nodes

I figured it would be easier to first load the nodes and then load relationships. To do so,  I extracted all unique terms (from `term_id`, `lang`, `term` and the `related-` versions) and wrote them to a CSV with 2,193,634 rows. Likewise, I have created a CSV of 3,884,337 relationship triples (`term_id`, `reltype`, `related_term_id`).

Since I would like to assign labels *dynamically*, I figured I needed to use APOC. I **successfully** loaded the nodes using the following:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///terms.csv') yield map as row return row",
    "CALL apoc.create.node(['row.language'], {term_id: row.term_id, term: row.term, language: row.language}) YIELD node RETURN node",
    {batchSize:10000, parallel:true}
)
```

### [Failure] Loading Relationships

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to perform a similar query to load relationships.

I was thinking about something along the lines of these:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///relationships.csv' AS row
WITH row
MATCH (a {term_id: 'row.term_id'}), (b {term_id: 'row.related_term_id'})
WITH row, a, b
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, 'row.reltype', {reltype: 'row.reltype'}, b) YIELD rel RETURN rel
```

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///relationships.csv') yield map as row return row",
    "MATCH (a {term_id: row.term_id}), (b {term_id: row.related_term_id}) ",
    "CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, row.reltype, {reltype: row.reltype}, b) yield rel return rel",
    {batchSize:10000, parallel:true}
)
```

...but various permutations of the above queries either seem to do nothing or throw errors.

### Question/Request

How can I quickly load these relationship triples into Neo4j while also dynamically assigning the relationship type/label?

Alternatively, is there a single query I could use to simultaneously (and dynamically) load the nodes and relationships from the original dataset?

I trust that the query is relatively straightforward, but being new to Neo4j, Cypher, and APOC, I can't quite figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think with the dynamic labels comes the task to also dynamically create the `CONSTRAINT`s before you start MERGEing stuff. So you may need to build some script / UI that allows you to

- detect the columns of the CSV
- select which columns correspond to IDs
- link id and other columns to entities
- create the `CONSTRAINT`s
- create the nodes
- add the relationships

you could end up with something like this : https://youtu.be/Yc0zzDgVFgk (disclosure: I work for Graphileon)